# How can I add a Jira dashboard to Confluence?

Tags: iframe, jira, dashboard, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I want add a [Jira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jira_(software)) dashboard to Confluence.

I tried with an iframe gadget and set the width to 1500 and the height as 1700.

But it displays as in this image:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Confluence and Jira on Cloud or on Server?

Comment: @stuck on cloud

Answer (score 0):

For Confluence Cloud, you cannot add the dashboard to the Confluence page at the moment. However, you can check and vote for [that ticket on Atlassian](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFCLOUD-70116) which is still gathering interest.

If you are able to buy a plugin (or use trial for some time) you can check [Table Filter and Charts for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/27447/table-filter-and-charts-for-confluence?tab=overview&hosting=cloud&utm_source=atl_community&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=table-filter-traffic-sources&utm_vendorID=1216111) plugin which helps to create dashboards inside the Confluence page.

Other than these two options, Jira macros may help you:

- [Jira Issues Macro](https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-the-jira-issues-macro/)
- [Jira Chart Macro](https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-the-jira-chart-macro/)
- [Jira Roadmap Macro](https://support.atlassian.com/confluence-cloud/docs/insert-the-jira-roadmap-macro/)